# Windows 10 Takes a lot of time launching "Choose Just-In-Time" Debugger Window

Tags: .net, windows, debugging, vscode-debugger

I'd like to debug a C# Console Application,
I've placed the following line in my code:
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();

Windows takes about a minute to pop up the "Choose Just-In-Time" Debugger Window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Windows try to look for a solution online, and only after it gives it a try it willing to open the debugger window,

To disable this behaviour you may be using Windows PowerShell (Run as Admin)

 **Disable-WindowsErrorReporting**


You should be prompt with 

**True**